# Where is the 'Deploy to..' button in JBoss Fuse IDE

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I'm using Ret Hat JBoss Developer Studio 8.1.0 as JBoss Fuse IDE, I already installed the JBoss Fuse project features, but I cannot find the 'Deploy to...' tool.
Although, it's mentioned here that I should find it in the IDE,
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Using_the_Fuse_Developer_Tools/files/FIDEDeployingContainer.html

Could anyone point me what I did wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the JBoss Fuse 6.2 documentation as its updated about the newer version of Developer Studio and how to deploy:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Tooling_User_Guide/RiderDeployPart.html